# Apache starts but with message: usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND

Tags: apache

Freshly installed Apache / PHP / Mysql on Arch Linux, the Apache server works fine but showing some POST 500 error and noticed in the error_log  file the following:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 28031] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28031] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1q PHP/8.1.11 configured -- resuming normal operations

[core:notice] [pid 28031] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

The SSL error I know i ve to regenerate the SSL certificates.
**What s with the message:  usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND**

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you did start the http server using the `FOREGROUND` option. So that it does not detach from the forking console.

Comment: That s the issue I didn't. Anyway:  #sudo /usr/bin/httpd -k stop -DFOREGROUND  seems to fixed it. Thank you